# can we make a BroadcastReceiver that detect when any installed app is launched(opened)

Tags: android

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class KeypadActivity extends Activity {
    static int flag = 1;
    Button btn0, btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4, btn5, btn6, btn7, btn8, btn9,
            btnclear, btnenter;
    TextView tv;
     String password;

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.keypad);
        addListenerOnButton();
    }

    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        btn0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn0);
        btn1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn2);
        btn3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn3);
        btn4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn4);
        btn5 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn5);
        btn6 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn6);
        btn7 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn7);
        btn8 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn8);
        btn9 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn9);
        btnclear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnx);
        btnenter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnenter);

        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        btn0.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn0.getText().toString());
            }
        });

        btn1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn1.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn2.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn3.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn4.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn5.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn5.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn6.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn6.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn7.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn7.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn8.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn8.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btn9.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                tv.append(btn9.getText().toString());
            }
        });
        btnclear.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String str = tv.getText().toString().trim();
                if (str.length() != 0) {
                    str = str.substring(0, str.length() - 1);

                    tv.setText(str);
                }
            }
        });


        btnenter.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub



                password=tv.getText().toString();
                Intent intent = new Intent(KeypadActivity.this, KeypadActivity2.class);
                intent.putExtra("password",password);
                startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
}}
```

i am making App-locker in Android, i have list of installed application in system. on clicking check boxes i set password on some of the application.now i want that how many apps i have locked with my application, if user open locked app then before opening that app my password verification activity(KeypadActivity.java) must be opened.

Comment: What would stop a user simply hitting the `BACK` button to finish your `Activity` and continue to use the other app without the need to enter a password?

Comment: ok. I'll make a BACK button. but how can i start my activity on launching the app that is locked(by clicking on check boxes).if my activity started then i'll ask for a password.